# Why does top's CPU breakdown (option 1) in default non-irix mode show conflicting results?

Tags: top, cpu-usage, processes

I'm running some benchmarks on various forks of `bitcoind` and I noticed some conflicting values when running `top`.

In the screenshot below, there is an even spread of ~30% cpu utilization across each of the 8 cpus. But in the list view below it, `bitcoind` shows 105% CPU. Given that this is not in Irix mode, that means that `bitcoind` is using 100% of 1 cpu. But it is not displaying that way in the breakdown above. Further, the Python processes I'm running report ~40% each in the bottom readout, but none of the cpus on top read ~40%.

The machine does indeed have 8 physical cores, running Ubuntu non-virtualized.

What's going on here?
[image: bitcoind top]

For comparison, here's running `stress` on 8 cpus with the same `top` display. Notice that 8 cpus each have 100% utilization, and the 8 `stress` processes each have a 100% report.
[image: stress top]

Update: indeed the variant I was testing is multithread and the `H` option showed the breakdown, thanks @TheGeek

[image: top-h]

Comment: there's absolutely no problem here. you have 800% of CPU available, top makes a ratio between the CPU time consume by your process and the CPU time a CPUi core is capable to handle. If you have a multi threaded process such as crypto mining the whole process if well written could consume 105% spread between all your CPU core. There's no problem here

Comment: @kiwy oh no problem here, the issue is with my understanding the output e.g. `PICNIC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your coind is multi-threaded. Press letter "H" in top to turn on threaded mode. This will show you child threads of bitcoind. You can then see the spread of CPU usage.

You can also try gstack  to see list of threads.